# Changing the partition problem to sum to specified bins

Tags: linear-algebra, programming

I'm struggling to mathematically define a solution to my problem which is a variant on the famous partition problem. Instead of partitioning a list of integers into two bins that sum to approximately an equal amount I want to partition a list of decimals such that each value goes into each equation once and only once and sums to a pre-specified value.

The simplest example of this I can think of is three values, 1,2, and 3 that I need to partition into two bins summing to 5 and 1.

Obviously this would yield two equations consisting of 1 = 1 and 2 + 3 = 5.

I can convert this into a simultaneous equation pretty easily but can't work out how to apply the constraint that each value can only go into each partition once.

Any advice would be appreciated, even if it's just to links I didn't know about. Sorry if this question hasn't been formulated the best way, first time poster!

Thanks!

EDIT: Thought I'd add a more concrete example that might make it clearer what I can change and what I can't.

Suppose I have a big box filled with legos. Each lego has some number of dots on the top. Now I have several smaller box's in front of me. I want the number of lego dots to sum to a specified (different) amount for each box. I can't change the number of legos I have, nor how many dots each one has, nor how many smaller boxes I have, nor the sum of dots for each box. Not every lego from the big box needs to be put into a smaller box. What I CAN choose is which legos to put in which boxes. I hope that's clear and not just random rambling.

Comment: Patitioning $1,2,3$ into two bins summing to $1$ and $5$ is the same as partitioning $1,2,3,4$ into two bins adding to the same number, isn't it? So your problem seems to be equivalent to the "famous" problem. Anyway, I think what you're looking for may be what's called "the subset sum problem", so have a look for that.

Comment: It may be equivalent to 1,2,3,4 into two bins adding to the same number but the problem has constraints. So how it is given would be, for example 1,2,3 and there is no alteration of that.
The two unalterable constraints are the number and selection of input numbers (the 1,2,3) and the number of bins and their sum (the 1,5).
The subset sum looks really interesting though, I'll check it out now, thanks!

Comment: If you have unalterable numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r$ and two bins and the unalterable sums of the bins are to be $s$ and $t$ with $s\le t$, then a solution to your question is equivalent to a solution to $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r,t-s$ into two bins each with sum $t$. You can solve one of those questions if and only if you can solve the other, and the complexity of solving one is exactly the same as the complexity of solving the other. I have reduced your problem to the other problem.

Comment: Ah I see! But does that same line of thinking work for up to N bins? Or only in the case of 2 bins.

Comment: Only two bins, I think. Another search term is *bin-packing problem*.